# SSRS 401.3 error access denied due to Access Control Lists

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

After uninstalling an Oracle 10 client / security patch (don't know what triggerd it) I'm having trouble with users accessing our SSRS test server.
First thing that happened was that the SQL service and SSRS service refused to start under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. When I changed that to local service both started...

I (as a domain admin) can access our reports but users (who are both browser / content manager on site settings & folder settings get:

```
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this    
request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources. 

Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the  
credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web 
server's administrator to give you access.
```

I'm almost at the point of restoring an image (don't prefer doing so since I've changed a lot since the image was made, yeah I know.. my mistake...), hope someone has a clue / idea?

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!
After granting the appropriate AD group read & execute rights on 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services the 401 disappeared!!

My users can connect to the report server and my .NET app can connect to the report service / asmx

Don't know what triggered it and why it's necessary to grant access on the file system but it's a quick relief compared to my alternatives..

Regards,

Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike! Fixed my problem immediately

Comment: Perfect ! You saved my life (y)