# SQL Reporting Services website not displaying properly for users

Tags: reporting-services

After upgrading our SQL Server to 2012 I set up and configured Report Services on the server and have added a couple of reports.  When I open the site, with my normal user account (not admin) it displays properly, see image.

[image: normal view]

When other users log in they get the page below and can open reports but not enter parameters/run the report.  I'm not sure why.  I've checked the permissions and they appear to be ok.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: other users view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in a slightly different but similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685452/ssrs-401-3-error-access-denied-due-to-access-control-lists).

It was a permission issue for domain users on the MSRS... folder on the server.  Once I added the read/execute permissions to that folder it rendered properly.